# Formik - Use uppercase first letter field name in error messages

Tags: javascript, react-native, formik

Is it possible to use uppercase field names in Formik error messages without having to define your own custom error message for every field? I'm using react native.

I have had to just name the Formik field values with capital letters but I would prefer not to do that.

formik enhancer code with uppercase first letter field names:

```
const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    Name: Yup.string().required(),
    Brand: Yup.string().required(),
    GroceryStore: Yup.object()
      .shape({
        city: Yup.string(),
        latitude: Yup.number(),
        longitude: Yup.number(),
        name: Yup.string(),
        place_id: Yup.string(),
        street: Yup.string(),
        street_number: Yup.string(),
        suburb: Yup.string()
      })
      .required(),
    Image: Yup.object().shape({
      uri: Yup.string(),
      name: Yup.string(),
      type: Yup.string()
    }),
    Categories: Yup.array()
      .min(1, 'Please select at least 1 Category')
      .required(),
    Description: Yup.string()
      .min(9)
      .required(),
    Price: Yup.string().matches(
      /^\d+(?:\.\d{2})$/,
      'Price must contain 2 decimal places (cents) e.g. 4.00'
    )
  }),
  isInitialValid: false,
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    Name: '',
    Brand: '',
    Description: '',
    Price: '',
    Categories: [],
    GroceryStore: {},
    Image: {}
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { props }) => {
    handleSubmit(values, props)
  },
  displayName: 'AddGroceryItemView'
})(AddGroceryItemView)
```

Comment: You can always try a css rule `text-transform: capitalize;`. I think it would work, not 100% sure as you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: did you mean field names like `Name` to be uppercase `NAME`, or did you mean the value of the field like `{ Name: "RIKIN" }`

Comment: @Rikin I mean the error message to be “Name is a required field”. But not just capitalise the first letter of the sentence. Capitalise the the field. Because sometimes the field is not the first word. Like “you must select one Category”. And I don’t want to have to do them all with custom messages just for that.

Comment: you can probably use some sort of custom function that returns `name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)`

Comment: @Rikin I don't know how to target the field name with that. The display error message in JSX  is like `{errors.Brand}` so it would be like: `{errors.Brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}` I don't think that'll work, it'll just target the first character of the error, but I will try it when I'm home.

Comment: Honestly this issue may not be worth your time in formatting, rather you should just drop those names in some sort of constant and use that constant in string creation for error message like: `error.Brand = \`My fancy ${BrandConstant} error message\`` and in usage of field name you can just use `{[BrandConstant]: value}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Provide a label instead.

So for `street: Yup.string()`, you can write `street: Yup.string().label('Street')`.
This will also help if you have more than one word like in `street_number`, so you need to write `street_number: Yup.string().label('Street Number')`